# Dump php variables gotten from POST

Tags: php

I have some PHP code running at the top of my page

```
if(isset($_POST['arrow1']) and isset($_POST['arrow2'])) {....}
```

And a form that sends data to this page. What i want to do is to empty the variables once the php code at the top runs so that on refresh it won't run again.

How can i achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: By manipulating the HTML produced after you have detected the form submission. In practice this means that you should do a [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the question is a little bit outdated but....

Your form will run only once... or everytime... depending on how you load the page. If the form submits POST, unsetting is kind of sinceless. Let´s say the form on the top says: 
Push button and submit "hello world". You push the button, page get´s load `(and since you dont use ajax, it has to load new)`, "hello world" is submitted and after submit POST get´s unset. Form is still there.. you press button again... same thing happens again. To avoid this you propably have to use `$_SESSION`

Sample

```
if((!isset($_SESSION['arrowsWasSet'])) 
{
    if(isset($_POST['arrow1']) and isset($_POST['arrow2']))
    {
        unset($_POST);
        $_SESSION['arrowWasSet'] = true;
    }
}
```

other way is to store data into the session and check if its already set to session.

```
if(isset($_POST['arrow1']) && isset($_POST['arrow2'])) 
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['arrows']))
    {
        $_SESSION['arrows']['arrow1'] = $_POST['arrow1'];
        $_SESSION['arrows']['arrow2'] = $_POST['arrow2'];
    }
    unset($_POST); 
    //you can call this to get a clean post everytime, but no need.
}
```

do you have a type in there ? i mean shouldnt this mean `array1` instead of `arrow1` ? :)

anyways, `$_SESSION` survives the refresh. So after refreshing the page, you can still check if something happend. To empty session you could do:

- **session_destroy** *(kills hole session)*
- **restart your Browser** (not refresh, totaly restart! kills hole session)
- **hitting keys** `ALT` + `F5` (kills hole session)
- **clear Browsercache manualy** (kills hole session)
- `$_SESSION['xy'] = NULL;` (kills parts in session)
- `unset($_SESSION['xy']);` (kills parts in session)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['arrow1']) and isset($_POST['arrow2'])) 
{
   unset($_POST);
}
```

Will unset all $_POST variables.
You could also do:

```
$_POST['arrow1'] = NULL;
$_POST['arrow2'] = NULL;
```

Comment: That would unset all POST data. From my understanding of OP only `arrow1` and `arrow2` should be emptied.

Comment: refreshing of the page has the same effect so what would you do?

Comment: You might want to set to null instead of an empty string. PHP might not be picky about it's type, but readability and your coder's sanity are ;)
PS: You can also `unset($_POST['arrow1']);`

Comment: @ToBe done. Though unsetting pretty much has the same effect as setting it to NULL^^

Comment: Absolutly, was purely cosmetic, but I think that's very important in the long run ;)
On second thought, if you set to NULL, the key should still be present in $_POST. Unsetting removes the whole element.

Comment: I think unseting is the way to go on this one but when i tried it yet it didnt have any results, page still run and queries still executed. Will try again now see if theres a mistake somewhere

Comment: actually this will never work. because on refresh the pages sends post again. unsetting post takes no effekt on refreshed/REloaded data. here you have to use sessions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect the user on the same page.

In this case, after the script execution, if he wants to refresh the page, there is no more variable in the header...

```
<?php
header("location:[your/path.php]");
```

Comment: Many browsers fail when you arent using absolute URLs in your redirect  header. Also, plz use upper case  `Location`. You wont believe how picky some browsers are, especially mobile ones fail when even a space is missing.